# Setup Github action to download a zip file

Tags: github, github-actions

I have a Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox extension in a same GitHub repository. They are separated in two branches and I am "exposing" the original URL to download the repository for each branch:

[image: Github download]

The approach to install a Firefox extension is quite long and messy since it needs to be unzipped and zipped again. So, someone recommended me using Github actions to create a release file from specific branches using this [Github action: Zip Release](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/zip-release).

According to [their documentation](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/zip-release#usage) I have tried to replicate the YAML file for my use case using the Github action creation wizard and naming that file `firefox.yml` that created a folder in the repository root: `.github/workflows/firefox.yml`:

```yaml
name: Create Archive
on: [push]
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: my-user/the-repo@dev-firefox
    - name: Create Firefox Release
      uses: thedoctor0/zip-release@main
      with:
        type: 'zip'
        filename: 'dev-firefox.zip'
        path: './releases'
        exclusions: '*.git* /*node_modules/* .editorconfig /*releases/*'
```

But after it starts it immediately fails with the following message:

> Can't find 'action.yml', 'action.yaml' or 'Dockerfile' under '/home/runner/work/_actions/my-user/the-repo/dev-firefox'. Did you forget to run actions/checkout before running your local action?

I also tried adding `- uses: actions/checkout@master` just before the line `- uses my-user/the-repo@dev-firefox` but it won't work.

Not sure how to properly write the workflow YAML configuration. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You're confusing `uses` with checking out a repository. `uses` indicates an action to use, with the part after the `@` specifying the version of the action. To check out a specific branch of your repo, you can use the `checkout` action with the `ref` parameter:

```yaml
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3.1.0
      with:
        ref: dev-firefox
```